# Simple, algorithm that buy something in Swift Coding

Tags: ios, swift

I want Subtract process with Button action but my code does not work.

I made the Number. This number is Main number for user's game money. I set the '1,000'. This I set the name of this "playerMoney"

After that I made the  @IBAction Button for Discount the '500' number from 'playerMoney'. This button's action means buy Game item things.
I set the name of '500' number is "chocolatePrice" and Button's name is "buyChocolateButton"

I also print playerMoney on the UILable.
I set that label name is "printPlayerMoney"

I'm using the code below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerMoney = 1000
    var chocolatePrice = 500
    @IBOutlet weak var printPlayerMoney: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buyChocolateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        playerMoney = playerMoney - chocolatePrice
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        printPlayerMoney.text = "\(playerMoney)"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: playerMoney -= chocolatePrice

Comment: I did that  code but wrong. ^0^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `printPlayerMoney.text = "\(playerMoney)"` inside the button function. That way, overtime you press the button, it does the calculation and then updates the label. See the updated code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerMoney: Int = 1000
var chocolatePrice: Int = 500

@IBOutlet weak var printPlayerMoney: UILabel!

@IBAction func buyChocolateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    playerMoney = playerMoney - chocolatePrice
    printPlayerMoney.text = "\(playerMoney)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printPlayerMoney.text = "\(playerMoney)"`

doesn't watch the value of `playerMoney`

After changing the value of `playerMoney`, we have to set the text of the UILabel again if we're expecting a visual change